# Error on opening Infopath form in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, browser-enabled-form

One of my user wants to edit the InfoPath form and enter some data. When she is trying to open the InfoPath form she is encountering below error. How can I over come this issue?

[image]

Comment: why three tags of sharepoint editions? which one are you using currently? enterprise, foundation or online?

Comment: Click on "show error details" and check for Correlation ID and then explore your ULS logs for details

Comment: Dear Zakir, We are using SharePoint Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Check that this is a browser-enabled form. It may be a Filler form that has been uploaded to the library and can only be edited with IP Filler.

Answer (score 0):

You may have published an InfoPath filler form to your form library. Review and check in the Form Options in InfoPath Designer if you have published an InfoPath filler form or Web Browser Form. If it is an InfoPath filler form then change it to Web Browser Form and republish the form again to your form library.

Open InfoPath Designer > File tab > Form Options > Compatibility > Form type.

Example:

[image]